# Randomly get failed to open stream: Permission denied with fopen()

Tags: php

It's actually working, it will open and work with file, but sometimes it shows up this error:

> Warning: fopen(some_address\backup.php): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in C:\Program Files(x86)...."

After refreshing the page (f5) everything works fine again, but still it's kinda annoying and thanks to this It's not too much "user friendly" code... Don't you know why?

```
private function doBackup($file){
        $file_index_content = file_get_contents($file);
        $file_backup = $this->Path."/backup.php";
        if(file_exists($file_backup)){
            unlink($file_backup);
            $file_backup_open = fopen($file_backup, "w"); //THIS ONE IS DOING THE ERROR!!
            fwrite($file_backup_open, $file_index_content);
            fclose($file_backup_open);
        }else{
            $file_backup_open = fopen($file_backup, "w");
            fwrite($file_backup_open, $file_index_content);
            fclose($file_backup_open);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You could essentially fix the issue and reduce that code to 3 lines by using `file_put_contents($file_backup, $file_index_content)`, (avoiding check exists, delete, write) the issue is happening because of the unlink before.

Comment: I'll try, thank you!

Comment: Amazing, thank you @LawrenceCherone !